# What are Pros and cons of deploying a new minimal proxy contract for every minted token vs minting all in a single contract?

Tags: evm, storage, merkle-patricia-tries, storage-trie, zkevm

[I am thinking about NFTs but it might be a broader idea]

It is intuitive to think that deploying a new minimal proxy contract exclusive for every new minted token (like an ERC721 with totalSupply of one) is more resource-intensive than minting several tokens on the same contract, but, is it really tho?

For storage, only two additional slots (64 bytes) are needed - the minimal proxy contract bytecode plus the logic contract address occupies exactly 45 bytes. But now we don't need another storage slot to hold the `tokenId` which represents an individual item (the whole contract does that). So realistically it just uses one single additional slot.

For runtime performance, since every proxy has a very small footprint (45 bytes) and is simply loading/forwarding all calls to a logic contract, there should not be any kind of disadvantage *if compared* to minting different items on a specific contract which is also a proxy contract.

Can anyone familiar with the inner workings of the EVM can say something about that?

Thanks ✌️

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of intuitive but there will be cons

1. It will have scalability issues.  Also you don't want to have 10k
   contracts, prefer to have a single contract
2. The runtime costs MAY increase because there is always an added
   delegatecall.
3. If you need to maintain a list of proxies deployed than you'll need to store it in storage(used in a places like marketplace)

Comment: 1) What scalability issues? why prefer a single contract? Note that a single contract with multiple tokens requires an additional tokenId whenever I want to interact with a token.
2) That does not change anything if comparing to using a single contract which also happens to be a proxy contract (there is a delegatecall in both cases).
3) Might actually be better to store a contract address (20 bytes) which fully represents an individual asset than to store a contract address plus a tokenId (20 + 32 bytes) to reference an individual asset.

Comment: 2) When interacting with a single contract(ERC721) there is no delegate call used. 3) If you want to query for ownerOf or transfer the NFT it's easier to use a single contract rather than a many proxies. It's the same contract for NFT of same collection but just unique tokenId(32 bytes). I'd suggest you to create a prototype using your idea